# search and replace a csv file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, replace

I've been working on a csv file.

I want to replace the the 3rd and 4th columns only.

Here is an example:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3              Col4             Col5   Col6               Col7
c1    f2    stack.overflow    stack.overflow   f5     stack.overflow     stack.overflow
d1    g2    stack2.overflow2  stack2.overflow2 xyx    stack2.overflow2   stack2.overflow2
```

I carry out the search and replace of Col3 and Col4 only.

What I get is:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3              Col4             Col5   Col6               Col7
c1    f2    macy.greytold     macy.greytold    f5     stack.overflow     stack.overflow
d1    g2    prince.caballero  prince.caballero xyx    stack2.overflow2   stack2.overflow2
```

I used sed:

```
 sed ' s!stack.overflow2!prince.caballero!g' filename.csv > test1.csv
 sed ' s!stack.overflow!macy.greytold!g' test1.csv > test-2.csv
```

But that changes the whole lot.  Is there a way to just change fields 3 and 4?

Please note that I have given an example of 2 lines. This can run on to 100 lines.

Comment: You should probably look into awk. It can work with the specified column and do replacement on it. I don't remember the exact syntax

Comment: Could you please confirm if your values can have spaces in between them eg: `stack overflow`?

Comment: You say your input is CSV but the sample input/output you provided is not CSV. Please [edit] your question to either change the description of your files from CSV to whatever they are (tab-separated? fixed-width fields? something else?), or change your example to be CSV.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 They are not spaces between them.

Comment: @EdMorton This is a CSV file and comma separated.  Just to make it easier to view I gave it like the example.

Comment: @mac please don't do that. Showing a graphical representation of your data instead of simply showing your data makes it harder for us to help you because then we can't just copy/paste your example to test with and you'll get solutions posted that assume your real input looks like your example and so solve a problem you don't actually have.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is a TSV file (tab-separated values) this is easy with Awk.

```
awk -F '\t' '$3 == "stack.overflow2" { $3 = "prince.caballero" }
    $4 == "stack.overflow2" { $4 = "prince.caballero" }
    $3 == "stack.overflow" { $3 = "macy.greytold" }
    $4 == "stack.overflow" { $4 = "macy.greytold" }
    1' filename.csv >updated.tsv
```

Awk processes one line (or, more generally, one record; you can change the record separator with `RS=value`) at a time. The variables `$1`, `$2` etc get the values of the respective fields on the line.  The `==` comparison simply checks for verbatim equality (please update the question if you want to match substrings of these fields, or e.g. case-insensitive matching) and the final `1` says to print every line.

In the general case, CSV and its variations allows for quoting of fields, which means not all records are a single line and not all field separators actually separate two fields, at which point using simple line-oriented tools like Awk may no longer be feasible. If you bump into these complications, look for a dedicated CSV processing tool, or switch to a language which comes with a proper CSV parser -- Python is one popular choice.

Comment: But the filename is very long and the fact we dont know what the names are going to be.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant to the question you asked or the answer I provided. If you need help with an unrelated problem, (accept one of the answers you got, or post an answer of your own and accept that if you prefer, and) ask a new question about that.